# Postgresql update json error with `invalid input syntax for type json, Token is invalid.`

Tags: json, postgresql

This is my *SQL* :

```
UPDATE "CET_User"
   SET "Property" = jsonb_set("Property",
                              '{"Tid"}',
                              '9323fce7-416e-40be-802f-ee173f246907')
 WHERE ("Property" - >> 'Tid') = '33bc69e8-0715-4b86-8611-67070c5c744d';
```

When i try to run it , it get a *error* :

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
> LINE 13: ...SET  "Property" = jsonb_set("Property",'{"Tid"}', '9323fce7-...
>                                                               ^
> DETAIL:  Token "9323fce7" is invalid.
> CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: 9323fce7...
> ```

*ref* :

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-json.html

I think i use the right syntax, is there any fault observed?

Answer (score 1):

Think abuout this value, `'9323fce7-416e-40be-802f-ee173f246907'`, the `jsonb_set` function need a `jsonb` value so it will try to translate to it.
Like `SELECT '9323fce7-416e-40be-802f-ee173f246907'::jsonb`, you need specify it is a string, `SELECT '"9323fce7-416e-40be-802f-ee173f246907"'::jsonb`

So, the answer is `UPDATE "CET_User" SET  "Property" = jsonb_set("Property",'{"Tid"}', '"9323fce7-416e-40be-802f-ee173f246907"')  WHERE ("Property"->>'Tid')  = '33bc69e8-0715-4b86-8611-67070c5c744d';`